# Get count and sum of one table based on other table based on other table

Tags: sqlite, join, count, sum, multi-table

I have 3 SQLite tables:

channel

```
channelId triad
1         1
2         1
3         0
```

video

```
channelId videoId topic
1         xx      1
1         yy      0
2         pp      0
3         kk      1
```

comment

```
commentId replyId videoId sentiment
NULL      er41     xx      -3
clxpo     NULL     kk      0.05
clutz     NULL     yy      2.38
NULL      edg15    xx      1.7
clopq     NULL     pp      1
dkt2      NULL     kk      0.95
```

For every channel where triad = 1 I need to know the sum of the sentiment from the channel videos where topic = 1 and the number of comments for that channel.

Keys are:

> channel.channelId = video.channelId
>
> video.videoId = comment.videoId

End result should be:

```
channelId sum(sentiment) count(number of comments) triad topic
1         -1,3           2                         1     1
```

How can I chain that 3 tables to get the needed result?

Comment: I don't get those results. ChannelId 3 has a Triad of 0 so why is it being counted? And how do you get 2.05 from channelid 1 comments? And nothing for 2?

Comment: And should the sum and count both be only of videos with topic 1, or is it sum of those with 1, and count of all?

Comment: edited the result table, you are right. ChannelId 2 has "triad" but videos for ChannelId 2 don't have "topic" so it gets left out. sum(sentiment) only for those channel and videos with topic=1 and triad=1, same for count.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now - except for a count of 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, working for 12 hours now, my brain is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a straightforward 3-way merge with some filtering to restrict it to just rows with `triad` and `topic` of 1, grouping on `channelid`:

```
SELECT ch.channelid
     , sum(co.sentiment) AS sum_sentiment
     , count(*) AS num_comments
FROM channel AS ch
JOIN video AS v ON ch.channelid = v.channelid
JOIN comment AS co ON v.videoid = co.videoid
WHERE ch.triad = 1 AND v.topic = 1
GROUP BY ch.channelid
ORDER BY ch.channelid;
```

which gives

```
channelid   sum_sentiment  num_comments
----------  -------------  ------------
1           -1.3           2
```

If you have a lot of rows in your tables, use the sqlite3 command line tool's [.expert command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) to figure out what indexes should be added for an optimized [execution plan](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).